# want to put and output of a list as a value of single key in a dictionary

Tags: python

i am new in python.I just working with the list and dictionary.I am looking for take a list value under key in a dictinary and want to show output the values of list under the associated key.for example,

if i have a list of different car name's such as

```
list = ['Toyota','Ferrery','Ford','Nisshan']
```

then i just want to take the list values in a dictionary under single key such as,

```
dict = {'Car_name': list_values }
```

how can i do that and how can i make an output such as

```
  Car_name : Toyota , Ferrary , Ford , Nisshan.
```

hope all you understand my question.
please help me out to fix the problem.

Comment: `d = { 'Car_name': lst }`. Don't use `dict`, `list` as variable names. It shadows builtin functions.

Comment: @falsetru Hey buddy! How are you?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, I'm all right. Thank you. How are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one can simply make a `dict` like so:

```
l = ['Toyota','Ferrery','Ford','Nisshan']
d = {'Car Names': l}
```

As for getting the output right:

```
l = ['Toyota', 'Ferrery', 'Ford', 'Nisshan']
d = {'Car Names': l}

for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, ':', str(value)[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

just for understanding

```
l = ['Toyota','Ferrery','Ford','Nisshan']
dictionary = {}
dictionary['Car_Names']=l #the value of key 'Car_Names ' would be the list l
print dictionary #it will give the result as u have asked
```

i hope it helps